# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link net/glxn/qrgen/javase/QRCode

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link net/glxn/qrgen/javase/QRCode
```

I get the above error when I added this code in my .pom file

```
<build>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>net.glxn.qrgen:javase</include>
                                    <include>org.json:json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </build>
```

I had to add maven-shade-plugin to add support for 3rd party plugin.

Any thoughts why I am getting this error ?

**Update**
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>keycloak-examples-providers-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0.Final</version>
    </parent>

    <name>HyperSign Authenticator</name>
    <description/>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>HyperSignAuth</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn.qrgen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>HyperSignAuth</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>net.glxn.qrgen:javase</include>
                                    <include>org.json:json</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dependency:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.glxn/qrgen/1.4
>
> ```
> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.glxn/qrgen -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
>     <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
>     <version>1.4</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: something to do with these i guess 

qrgen-core-2.0
qrgen-javase-2.0
zxing-core-3.1.0
zxing-javase-3.1.0

Comment: Look at these two links: [NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use external library to generate QR codes](https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/noclassdeffounderror-when-trying-to-use-external-library-to-generate-qr-codes/2286) and [Integrating QR code library](https://techblaag.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/integrating-qr-code-library/)

Comment: Oh man this is very painful, I can't believe the author of those library are using bad practice. I think Ill generate an encrypted string and Populate the QR code in Javascript in the FTL file :D, You are more experienced to me what do you think of this approach ?